# Get the longest period where most columns overlap in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple timeseries each representing a column in a dataframe.
I need to clean the data in the sense that I would like to remove the columns that have gaps or find the longest period where all columns have data.
For example for the toy dataset:

```
            AEDC    AGGI    AKVA    ALME    ALOD    ALTX    
2014-01-02  NaN     0.03    0.04    0.0040  0.38    NaN     
2014-01-03  NaN     NaN     58.3    0.0040  NaN     0.083   
2014-01-06  NaN     NaN     58.9    0.0063  NaN     0.083   
2014-01-07  NaN     NaN     NaN     0.0065  NaN     0.083   
2014-01-08  NaN     0.04    NaN     0.0080  NaN     NaN
```

The period which I would select is 2014-01 : 03-2014-01-06 because there I have overlap for 3 columns.
Is there a library that would help me in achieving this goal?

Comment: Hi, asking for library recommendations is out of the scope of stack overflow. To ask for help, please write some code with a reproducable example...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the presence of `NaN` in the dataframe and then add across rows to figure out the number of non-na columns in each row. Then run some sort of run length encoding to obtain the runs of equal values.

```
import pdrle

rle = pdrle.encode(df.notna().sum(axis=1))
rle["run_end_ind"] = rle.runs.cumsum()
rle["run_start_ind"] = rle.run_end_ind - rle.runs
rle

   vals  runs  run_end_ind  run_start_ind
0     4     1            1              0
1     3     2            3              1
2     2     2            5              3
```

From the second row of the `rle` in the example above, we see that in rows with index `1` (`run_start_ind`) through index `3` (`run_end_ind`) of `df`, there were `3` (`vals`) columns with non-na values.